# Retrieve specific value on eloquent query

Tags: laravel

I would like to get only some values on these 3 different models:

1 user can have 1 rank
1 user can have X tchatMessages

I query the model tchatMessage, passing by the model User and I access its Rank relation.

In tchatMessage I would like to get :

- content
- created_at

In User :

- username

In Rank :

- color
- icon

Here is my current query which retrieves all the data from the three models:

```
return TchatMessage::with(['user' => function($user){
    $user->with(['rank'])->get();
}])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(2)->get();
```

Relations :

In User :

```
public function tchatMessages()
{
  return $this->hasMany(TchatMessage::class);
}
```

In TchatMessage

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

In User to :

```
public function rank()
{
  return $this->belongsTo( 'App\Models\Rank' );
}
```

Edit 2:

This query works, I've the username only but all fields in rank, how can I select only color & icon in rank model ?

```
return TchatMessage::query()
            ->with(array('user' => function($query) {
                $query->select('id','rank_id','username')
                    ->with('rank');
            }))
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(2)->get();
```

Edit 3: (works)

```
return TchatMessage::query()
            ->with(array('user' => function($query) {
                $query->select('id','rank_id','username')
                    ->with('rank:id,color,icon');
            }))
            ->select('content', 'user_id', 'created_at')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(2)->get();
```

Comment: Add `->with('rank:color,icon');`

Comment: edit 3 works, but this is secure to display rank_id, user_id in the result ??

Comment: I do a map, and it works perfectly, thanks u

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `select` filter everywhere, like this :

```php
return TchatMessage::query()
    ->select('content', 'created_at')
    ->with([
        'user' => function ($user) {
            $user->select('username');
        }, 
        'user.rank' => function ($rank) {
            $rank->select('color', 'icon');
        }])
    ->orderByDesc('created_at')
    ->limit(2)
    ->get();
```

And you can find more ways to do it, [following this link](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/23516)

EDIT:

About your relations, following the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships), you can try to do like this :

User model :

```
public function tchatMessages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TchatMessage::class);
}

public function rank()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Rank::class);
}
```

Rank model :

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

TchatMessage model :

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

EDIT 2:

With your query it works, so you can try :

```
return TchatMessage::query()
    ->select('content','created_at')
    ->with(['user:username' => function($user){
        $user->with(['rank:color,icon'])->get();
    }])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(2)->get();
```

You can also let your query like this and add where conditions in your relations, something like this for example for you rank relation in your User model (if you don't need this relation somewhere else) :

```
public function rank()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Rank::class)->select(['color', 'icon']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Jérome, but when I dd(), user is null, do you have an idea why ?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your relations please ?

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: @Kylian I edited my post, be sure you have data in your database and let me know

Comment: Same thing, nothing in user when I die dump

Comment: With my query it works but I have all the fields

Comment: @Kylian I edited my answer

Comment: I edited my post to